# What is the meaning of キロ四方?

Tags: meaning, translation

Especially in the context of this sentence:

> およそ二十キロ四方の巨大な湖は、ひっくり返した瓢簞のような形をしており、上の湖と下の湖に分かれている。

To my understanding, this sentence translates as "This lake was approximately twenty square kilometers in size, and resembled an inverted gourd, divided into an upper and lower lake." But I've seen a translation which said "This enormous lake had a radius of approximately twenty kilometers," which I don't particularly get. キロ四方 means 'square kilometer', right? Is "radius of 20 kilometers" a mistranslation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say neither of the translations is correct. 20キロ四方 basically means "20 km × 20 km" (that is, 400 km<sup>2</sup>). 四方 literally means "four sides (of a square)". 平方キロ is the word for "square kilometer" (平方 = square, x<sup>2</sup>).

- 20キロ四方 = 20 km × 20 km
- 20平方キロ = 20 km<sup>2</sup> = 20 square kilometers

<sup>(Confusingly, we also say 20キロ平方, which literally means "20 kilometer's square" and thus is a synonym for 20キロ四方 = 20 km × 20 km.)</sup>

For example, [this article](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/383e2a618fdb43fa1ee18a8f9504403385570e9e) says 5キロ四方 referring to a 5 km square grid (i.e., each cell is 25 km<sup>2</sup> in area).

キロ四方 is usually used with square-like objects, but of course a real lake is not square. In a case like this, you can think it's roughly 20 km in *diameter* (not *radius*), or "20 km from north to south and 20 km from east to west".

Comment: But it's kinda hard to imagine an inverted gourd shape (I'm picturing something shaped a bit like an 8) having something you can call a diameter.

Comment: @user40750 Correct, please see the edit. Basically you can imagine a "bounding box" of 20km四方 (20 km × 20 km).